# Javascript Onclick=window.open() function will open a new page every time I refresh the page?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, onclick, refresh, window.open

So I have a DIV element that, when pressed, I want to open a new tab in a different window. The only problem is, whenever the page is refreshed or any other div element is pressed, th function is initiated as well and opens a page in another window. I'll include my code below, but I'm not sure why this is happening seeing as how I'm using `onClick={window.open("https://www.thechinesewriter.com")` Like I said, I only want a new tab to open when the div is pressed, not when any other items on the page are clicked or even when the page itself is refreshed.

```
import React from "react";
import "./Column1.css";

class Column1 extends React.Component {

    render() {
        return(
            <React.Fragment>
                 <div className="rectImage">
                     <img className="imagePost" src={this.props.image} />   
                 </div>
                 <div onClick={window.open("https://www.thechinesewriter.com")} className="downloadBut1">
                     <h2>
                         Source
                     </h2>
                 </div>
                 <div className="downloadBut2">
                     <h2>
                         Repository
                     </h2>
                 </div>
             </React.Fragment> 
         )
     }     
}

export default Column1;
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to call the function as a callback like this.

```
<div onClick={() => window.open("https://www.thechinesewriter.com")} className="downloadBut1">
```

Otherwise this gets called every time the component gets rendered.

Answer (score 3):

You use an expression, which will execute everytime the component is rendered.

```js
<div onClick={window.open("https://www.thechinesewriter.com")} className="downloadBut1">
```

You probably mean to use a function

```js
<div onClick={() => window.open("https://www.thechinesewriter.com")} className="downloadBut1">
```